# Dispose Simple Injector async scope in hangfire jobfilter lifecycle

Tags: c#, simple-injector, hangfire

I'm using Hangfire along with simple injector. I would like to do some logging if a job failed or succeeded. As far as I know, `OnStateElection` is the place to handle this.

However, since `OnPerforming` is called before this method, my scope is disposed. I've based this code on a [boilerplate](https://github.com/jmpichardo/aspnet-core-simple-injector-hangfire-boilerplate/blob/master/ASPNetCoreHangfire/SimpleInjector/SimpleInjectorAsyncScopeFilterAttribute.cs).

Is `OnStateElection` a reliable place to move the disposal to? If so, what context property should I rely on before disposing? `OnStateElection` is called more than once per iteration from what I've seen.

```
public class HangfireActivityJobFilter : JobFilterAttribute, IServerFilter, IElectStateFilter
{
    private static readonly AsyncScopedLifestyle Lifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

    private readonly Container _container;

    public HangfireActivityJobFilter(Container container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public void OnPerforming(PerformingContext filterContext)
    {
        AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(_container);
    }

    public void OnPerformed(PerformedContext filterContext)
    {
        var scope = Lifestyle.GetCurrentScope(_container);
        scope?.Dispose();
    }

    public void OnStateElection(ElectStateContext context)
    {
        _container.GetInstance<ILogger>(); // <-- OnPerformed called, scope disposed
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure which implications this will have for your design. Bu I myself don't use the boilerplate integration. I wrote an answer [here](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/617#issuecomment-424628931) on another way to integrate. You easily could decorate `IJobHandler<TJob>` to perform the logging.

Comment: @Ric.Net Thanks for the suggestion